# Tableau hide parameter header when parameter value is "hide"

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop, tableau-prep

I have a tableau table that looks like below

[image]

Here, I have created 3 parameters (and corresponding calculated fields).

a) Level_1_selected_dimension

b) Level_2_selected_dimension

c) Level_3_selected_dimension

Each of the parameter has a value called `hide` which is to turn off the drilldown.

For example, user can choose values for `Level_1_selected_dimension` and `Level_2_selected_dimension` but decide to not select any value from 3rd parameter (`Level_3_selected_dimension`). Hence, the value is set as `hide` for 3rd parameter as shown below

[image]

But the problem now, the header for 3rd level is still shown/displayed in tableau as shown above in my post?

How can I turn off the header/hide the header for 3rd level (as value for 3rd level is `hide`)?

I expect my output to look like below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve this, we need to create another parameters for labels to hide and show the Level 1,2,3 value for example if Level 1 ='hide' then ' ' else Level 1 and use this parameter as Label instead of original dimension. There is no direct way to hide the columns in tableau.